# Can't validate my Factur-X/ZUGFeRD file because of Specification: ISO 19005-3:2012, Clause: 6.2.3, Test number: 1

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, zugferd, pdfa3

I am trying to generate valid Factur-X/ZUGFeRD file using GhostScript.

I think I am very close to having a good result but there's still one last thing blocking. When I try to validate my PDF with [and online validator](https://www.zugferd-community.net/en/open_community/validation) or [VeraPDF](https://verapdf.org/), i am getting this error in return :

> The profile stream that is the value of the DestOutputProfile key shall either be an output profile (Device Class = "prtr") or a monitor profile (Device Class = "mntr"). The profiles shall have a colour space of either "GRAY", "RGB", or "CMYK".

Here is the command line I use to generate my file :

```
gswin64 --permit-file-read=C:\source\repos\test_gs\  
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFA=3 -sColorConversionStrategy=RGB 
-sZUGFeRDXMLFile=C:\source\repos\test_gs\xmlfile.xml 
-sZUGFeRDProfile=C:\source\repos\test_gs\sRGB_v4_ICC_preference.icc -sZUGFeRDVersion=2p1 -sZUGFeRDConformanceLevel=BASIC 
-o C:\source\repos\test_gs\output.pdf
C:\source\repos\test_gs\zugferd.ps
C:\source\repos\test_gs\input.pdf
```

`zugferd.ps` is the default file that can be found in /lib folder of GhostScript.

`sRGB_v4_ICC_preference.icc` can be found [there](https://www.color.org/srgbprofiles.xalter), I also tried with `sRGB2014.icc` for the same result.

If you need any more information please let me know.

Comment: 'sRGB' is a calibrated RGB space, it isn't 'RGB'. Try using an RGB profile.

Comment: Does gs show any error or maybe something like "falling back to pdf"?